# how to generate meta tags just like facebook's linter does

Tags: php, facebook

I'm doing a project in which I have to show the project description to the app user and what I have is the url of the product, the url could be from any site it could be the product url from amazon, ebay etc after searching a lot I found that the facebook's linker does the same thing that I want for my project that is generating the meta tags from single url, after generating the meta tags I will get the information i needed from those tags but the question is how to generate those tags.

Below is the code in my product.php I used to debug on facebook linter

```
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.amazon.com/Programming-PHP-Rasmus-Lerdorf/dp/0596006810/ref=pd_sim_b_4" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="social" />
<meta property="fb:profile_id" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />     
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I pressed the debug button, it generates the meta tags as shown below
[image]

I want to show exactly the same output that facebook linter generate to show the product image, description to my user.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right...

Your sites meta tags:

```
<meta name="custom_image_tag" content="http://yoursite.com/images/product_1.jpg" />
<meta name="custom_description_tag" content="The product description" />
```

Php code to fetch the tags

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.yoursite.com/some-page.html');

echo $tags['custom_image_tag'];
echo $tags['custom_description_tag'];
```

As for Amazon you could use their title meta tag and scrap images from the page.

Comment: Austin, there's no image index in tags array and the product and keywords return the same data, I only want the product image and product description

Comment: I was showing you the concept. There is no standard image or product tag, these custom to each site.